# django test (nose) stuck after add package fixtures

Tags: django, nose, fixtures, django-nose

I have django test run with nosetests.

But after I add [package fixtures](http://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-fixture-reference/#package), python manage.py test can't run as normal and get stuck.

package fixtures (I had minimize it to debug failure reason):

```
def setup_package():
    pass

def teardown_package():
    pass
```

And after I run test as normal, the shell get stucked:

```
$ python manage.py test myapp
```

Comment: Do the tests get stuck even with empty `setup_package()` and `teardown_package()` functions - i.e. with the function bodies set to `pass`?

Comment: @WillKeeling Sorry, It turns out that my carelessness causes this error.